# still walks with a limp

Tags: meaning, adverbs, adverb-placement

a. He still walks with a limp.

b. He walks with a limp still.

c. He walks still with a limp.

Are all of the above grammatically correct?

Do they all mean the same?

In there any difference in emphasis?

Many thanks.

Comment: They all mean the same; (c) might have been acceptable in archaic English but would never be used today.

Answer (score 1):

They are correct, but the second two need punctuation.

*"He walks with a limp, still".*

Without the comma it would mean that he was walking with a 'still' (a device to distil spirits), and the still was limp. (Although obviously no native speaker would actually interpret it that way.)

*"He walks, still with a limp."*

Is correct with a comma. Otherwise your are saying he walks still, which is not easy.

If you think of it in a sentence such as:

*"He walks everyday, still with a limp, into the town to meet her"*

it sounds quite natural.